# KeePass - possible to store and retrieve passwords for exe files. How?

Tags: keepass

I use some programs that require a password to be used ( i.e. Win SCP) Is it possible to start that program and fill out the password via KeePass without having to copy /paste but with the chosen shortcut? ( sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Is AutoType what you want, perhaps? Or do you need more automation?

Answer (score 2):

KeePass Professional (2.x) has an auto-type feature, I guess it's also available in KeePass Classic (1.x).

Auto-type switches to the window that was focused before switching to KeePass and automatically types your username, then simulates <kbd>Tab</kbd> key press to navigate to password field and proceeds to type the password, finally it presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm. This sequence of keys can be modified individually for each entry.

There are two ways to invoke auto-type:

- By right-clicking an entry and selecting *Perform Auto-Type* - you have to switch to KeePass and select entry manually, or
- With a system-wide hotkey - I'm using <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for this purpose, it's configurable in *Tools → Options → Integration* tab. When the hotkey is pressed, KeePass asks for password to unlock current database (unless it's already unlocked), checks the title bar of focused window (in this case WinSCP window) and searches database for entries with matching name, then enters credentials like when it's invoked manually. You can also configure it to search entry URLs and tags for a match.

I guess the hotkey method is what you need.

Comment: The shortcut for " right-click an entry and select Perform Auto-Type" is to click on the entry and hit Ctrl V
This is in KeePass v1.x